# Hide non observed categories in a seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot, categorical-data

I am currently working on a data analysis, and want to show some data distributions through seaborn boxplots.

I have a categorical data, 'seg1' which can in my dataset take 3 values ('Z1', 'Z3', 'Z4'). However, data in group 'Z4' is too exotic to be reported for me, and I would like to produce boxplots showing only categories 'Z1' and 'Z3'.

Filtering the data source of the plot did not work, as category 'Z4' is still showed with no data point.

Is there any other solution than having to create a new `CategoricalDtype` with only ('Z1', 'Z3') and cast/project my data back on this new category?

I would simply like to hide 'Z4' category.

I am using seaborn 0.10.1 and matplotlib 3.3.1.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

My tries are below, and some data to reproduce.

**Dummy data**

```py
dummy_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'col2': [12., 5., 3., 2]})
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(dummy_cat)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='col1', y='col2')
```

[image: dummy data]

**Apply no filter**

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 25), nrows=len(indicators2), squeeze=False)
for j, indicator in enumerate(indicators2):
    sns.boxplot(data=orders, y=indicator, x='seg1', hue='origin2', ax=axs[j, 0], showfliers=False)
```

Which produces:

[image: Non filtered data]

**Filter data source**

```py
mask_filter = orders.seg1.isin(['Z1', 'Z3'])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 25), nrows=len(indicators2), squeeze=False)
for j, indicator in enumerate(indicators2):
    sns.boxplot(data=orders.loc[mask_filter], y=indicator, x='seg1', hue='origin2', ax=axs[j, 0], showfliers=False)
```

Which produces:

[image: Filter data source]

Comment: When I run your code, I get your desired plot without 'Z4'.  Are you sure you are running the latest version of seaborn (0.10.1)?

Comment: Looks like I am a couple versions late, I am running seaborn 0.8.1. I will test after having upgraded to the latest one.

Comment: I updated my seaborn library to 0.10.1 (matplotlib being 3.3.1 therefore up to date) and I still experience this issue. Are you sure that when you tested `seg1` was a `CategoricalDtype`?

Comment: What would be the problem converting your column to string? `df.col1 = df.col1.astype(str)`?

Comment: You could also reset the `xlim`s: `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JohanC, indeed it worked by simply converting to string (although it will obviously not keep the categories order, the data ploted being categorical no more). I don't know if this is in agreement with the etiquette, but I will post this suggestion as the answer in the afternoon, unless you do it before me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cut off the last (or first) x-value, `set_xlim()` can be used, e.g. `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)`.

Another option is to work with seaborn's `order=` parameter and only add the desired values in that list. Optionally that can be created programmatically:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dummy_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'col2': [12., 5., 3., 2]})
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(dummy_cat)
order = [cat for cat in dummy_cat.categories if df['col1'].str.contains(cat).any()]
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='col1', y='col2', order=order)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: This is great! I did not think about using the `order` parameter to filter out unwanted categories. This also enables to fine tune the order of categories. I also used the `hue_order` parameter in the same fashion to filter "hued" categories. Many thanks!